# Reading back own registration code from VS2010 C# Express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The original VS2010 C# key of my installation is lost, but still used in the running installation.

I tried to google it but i failed to find good keywords.
I tried to use the VS2010 menu but i did not find the key there.

Where is the key stored and how can i read it back?

Comment: Express Edition is free, can't you just get a new key?

Comment: Well yes.. but i would rather reuse my old one :) Getting a new one is  plan B :)